# Contradiction in logic gates

Tags: logic-gates

I have something with 4 inputs and 1 output, but the output is always 0. How can I show relationship between the 4 inputs and the output in logic gates?

Is it okay If I show it like this expression?

$$F=(\overline{X_1}\cdot X_1)\cdot(\overline{Y_1}\cdot Y_1)\cdot(\overline{X_0}\cdot X_0)\cdot(\overline{Y_0}\cdot Y_0)$$

Where \$X_1,Y_1,X_0,Y_0\$ are inputs, and \$F\$ is the output.

Comment: Unclear expression

Comment: @lancovici I've edited it

Comment: Ok, how about this. Use ~ or ! for logical not. Use & for logical and, and use | for logical or. Then if you find time and patience, create a truth table of the output based on the input. Note you'll want to use boolean algebra rules to simplify this redundant expression.

Comment: You should have edited the other one http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221842/contradiction-in-logic-gates instead of starting a new one.

Comment: So F is always 0 regardless of what the four inputs are? If so the expression is `F = 0`, since it is **regardless** of what the four inputs are

Comment: As soon as you have x and !x in a product, you know the result is identically 0.

Comment: @Iancovici better to use **!** for 'not', as **~** is often used for 'about', so still can be confusing.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: In C-like computer languages, `~` represents a bitwise inversion, while `!` represents logical negation. Both are appropriate here. "About" is not a valid concept in two-valued logic.

Answer (score 3):

> I have 4 input and 1 output and this output is always 0. How can I show relations between 4 input and this output in logic gates?

You don't.  The output has no dependence on the inputs, so it is silly to show it that way.

Think of the implementation if that helps.  To implement the logic you describe, the output is a just a wire to ground, and the inputs are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you have some assignment that requires representing the relationship between any number of inputs and an output that is always constant, then the relationship is simply that there isn't one.

$$F = 0$$

Nothing more. It doesn't depend in any way on the inputs, so they shouldn't be included in any Boolean expression for the output.

If you **have** to include them (for some undisclosed reasons), then simply:

$$F = 0 \cdot X_0 \cdot X_1 \cdot Y_0 \cdot Y_1$$

But that simply convolutes the relationship.